# Is the Webdings font available on most platforms?

Tags: fonts

I was thinking about using some arrow characters from the Webdings font on a website of mine.  However, I want to ensure it will work across most browsers/platforms.

Does anyone have any experience with Webdings that could tell me which platforms have it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Safari on a Mac, and I [can't see it](http://www.visibone.com/htmlref/char/webdings.html). I would simply assume that not everyone will see it, and use some of of [image-replacement](http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2009/03/31/dynamic-font-replacement-solutions) technique.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode defines [several arrow characters](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html) and a lot of people will have a reasonably complete unicode support in their fonts. Using unicode will probably work better than trying to mix character sets and specific fonts.